# Is there a step that will not cause an error? bufferTimeout: "Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests"

Tags: spring, project-reactor

API: [Exception - reactor-code](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/3.4.0/api/reactor/core/Exceptions.html#failWithOverflow-java.lang.String-)

The example works as follows:

- Subscribes to the next one on departure. The incoming data comes from the Rabbit and it will be processed. This can take a relatively long time and the result will send into another Rabbit queue.
- Because of bulk processing, I use buffer for 10 elements. If not receive enough elements for 10, I use a timeout (on buffer) to release for processing.

**Problem:** If processing or rabbit publisher is slow, bufferTimeout not receive "request", when timeout run out bufferTimeout would like to emit. Then I get the following Exception: *"Could not emit buffer due to lack of requests"*

Since I need all the data, I exclude next method usage: onBackPressureDrop or onBackPressureLatest. Using plain onBackPressure won't be good because it is not forward the received request number. (o*nBackPressure use request(unbound) not request(n)*)

**Example Kotlin code:**

```kotlin
@Configuration
class SpringCloudStreamRabbitProcessor {
    @Bean
    fun rabbitFunc() = Function<Flux<Int>, Flux<Int>> {
        it.bufferTimeout(10, Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            .concatMap { intList ->
                // process
                Mono.just(intList)
            }
            .flatMapIterable { intList -> 
                intList
            }
    }
}
```